# How might I apply fadein/fadeout to full-size image when clicking thumbs?

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, fadein, fadeout

I am stuck trying to apply a simple fadein/fadeout effect to a full-size image when clicking on thumbnail images. The jQuery script I am currently using switches the full-size image when I click the thumbnails. Now I want to apply the fadein/fadeout effect. Any tips/advice on how to accomplish this?

Here is the jQuery script I am using:

```
$("#work_thumbs").on("click", "img", function(){
    $("#work_largeImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("thumb","large"));
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="work_gallery">
  <div id="work_panel"><img id="work_largeImage" src="http://wedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ICON_FACEBOOK.svg" /></div>
  <div id="work_thumbs">
     <div class="thumbs_work_display"><img src="http://wedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ICON_FACEBOOK.svg" alt="" /></div>
     <div class="thumbs_work_display"><img src="http://wedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ICON_TWITTER.svg" alt="" /></div>
     <div class="thumbs_work_display"><img src="http://wedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ICON_INSTAGRAM.svg" alt="" /></div>
     <div class="thumbs_work_display"><img src="http://wedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ICON_BEHANCE.svg" alt="" /></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`?

Comment: I've attempted using these but am not certain where to place them in the code. I've gotten the full-size image to fade out but no luck in fading back in.

Comment: `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` (and most if not all other animation functions) have callbacks that allow you to execute code after the animation has finished. The simplest thing to do would be to put the `fadeIn()` call in the callback of the `fadeOut()` call.

Comment: I'm pretty new to the scripting world. How would I incorporate this in the code I am currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chaining the accomlish it. The hide() method makes sure it starts as hidden and then fadeIn() will make a nice transition.

```
$("#work_thumbs").on("click", "img", function(){
    $("#work_largeImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("thumb","large"))
        .hide()
        .fadeIn();
});
```

Register click event on the larger image to fade it out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#work_largeImage').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    }
});
```